# finding ram type with perl/cmd windows

Tags: windows, perl, ram, wmic

I am creating a script that gathers the pc specs(windows) and mails em to the tech support.

currently I am stuck on finding the RAM type.

`systeminfo` only shows me the ammount available.

i have been able to find a lot of info using `wmic memorychip get xxxx,xx` but I can't seem to find what type of RAM is being used

cpu-z shows me it is DDR3 but how did cpu-z get that information?

I am making this script in perl so perhaps perl has a module that I'm not aware of which lets me do this?

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Data like this may be available via Windows APIs but programs like CPU-Z include drivers that run with privileges that give access to kernel APIs and the underlying hardware. You may be better advised to get a textual report from CPU-Z or another program and parse its output to form the data you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're packaging a perl interpreter for distribution with this script, why don't you include a cpu-z binary in the package, have your script run it with output to a file arguments set, then parse that output for the information you need? Or just email that file as an attachment on top of the other information you include?

Ref: http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html

> `-txt=report` Launch CPU-Z in ghost mode : no interface appears, the register dump (report.txt) is automatically created.
>
> Example: `cpuz.exe -txt=c:\mydirectory\mysystem`: runs CPU-Z in ghost
>   mode. Report file mysystem.txt is automatically generated in directory
>   `c:\mydirectory`.

Answer (score 0):

Never tested this because I dont have a windows machine, but try

```
use Win32::SystemInfo;
use Data::Dumper;
my %mem;
Win32::SystemInfo::MemoryStatus(%mem, 'GB');
print Dumper %mem;
```